# Preventing Google Calendar API V3 from changing event times C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, google-calendar-api

I'm really running into some issues with timezones & haven't had luck with other similar questions.

Basically I want to create & share a Google Calendar event between two people, but I want the DateTime I provide for Start/End to be EXACTLY that & not converted for either of them. I'm in UTC-5, and when I test the events I'm receiving them 5 hours in the past, even though I set the timezone to UTC, strip the "Z" from the date, and set DateTimeKind to local...

The things I've tried:

```
DateTimeRaw = DateTime.ParseExact(appointment.Start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").Replace("Z", "")
```

And then the above but with .ToUniversalTime() added to appointment

```
DateTime = new DateTime(appointment.Start.Year, appointment.Start.Month, ....)
```

And also...

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.ParseExact(appointment.Start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTimeKind.Local)
```

I also tried the above with DateTimeKind.UTC

I've basically been trying a ton of combinations and then decided to stop because I don't really know why it's not working...

Is it possible to preserve the exact same time for all users in Google Calendar? I had used the ICAL.NET library before this & made my own .ics events and it worked perfectly, but the same DateTime code for GCal seems to not work as expected.

Edit:

Some more background on the reasoning for what I'm trying to do. I'm working on a SaaS scheduling application that deals with in-person appointments, but we have no knowledge of where specifically the locations will be. The way we address this is that on the UI & in the stored values every appointment is in UTC, so they see 5pm, select 5pm, stored as 5pm, and eventually should be shared as a Google Calendar event for 5pm. If the user is in a different timezone it will still show 5pm (as everything is UTC), but the expectation is that they'll be in the timezone of the scheduled location for the actual appointment.

We're switching to Google Calendar from sending .ics attachments and the same code for Start/End breaks for Google Calendar specifically.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot create the calendar events with your timezone? Will the viewers be on different time-zones?

Comment: I won't necessarily know the timezone of either user that the event is being shared with, but the event should show the exact same hh:mm for both. Because all events will be "in-person" we treat everything as UTC which would reflect the correct time (even in TZ changes) for each individual location.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Calendar

When you create a calendar event, you create it by default on your current timezone.

If you want multiple users to have the same event, at the same time, you just need to make sure that each user [has their calendar settings on the correct timezone](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064).

If you want to create an event on another timezone that is not your own, you can [specify the timezone to the API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource).

> The time zone in which the time is specified. (Formatted as an IANA Time Zone Database name, e.g. "Europe/Zurich".) For recurring events this field is required and specifies the time zone in which the recurrence is expanded. For single events this field is optional and indicates a custom time zone for the event start/end.

## Edit

If you are creating your own scheduling application and want to display these events on Google Calendar you can [embedded a Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207) with a specific time-zone.

However, if you are dealing with multiple users that might have different time-zones, it's important to account for that. Your application design is flawed in that aspect and does not support these use-cases.

You mentioned that you are selling a scheduling SaaS application, so I'll use that to generate a business-case to justify my thoughts:

> Imagine you have a class with 1 professor (in the US), 1 student (also in the US) and two other students from Japan.
>
> The professor will schedule a class at 1PM at this local time.
>
> Since the class is online, all students need to be available at that time, regardless of their timezone.
>
> If I want to add an event to everyone's calendar, I won't be marking 1PM on every calendar. I will be marking the equivalent time on the user's timezone.

Comment: So with the Google Calendar API is it not possible to show the same event across multiple user's timezones with the same hh:mm? 

EDIT: Sorry hit enter too early - I will *not* know the users timezones, just their emails. When creating .ics files manually & sharing those I was able to strip TZ data out and it worked fine, but it seems like that doesn't work with Google Calendar. But as mentioned, I won't know their timezones.

Comment: No, Google Calendar will show the event on the timezone of the user that is looking at it (or the configured timezone). If you want all your users to see the same HH:MM value, you will have to configure your calendar to the same timezone or create one calendar per timezone, and assign it accordingly.
What is the problem you are trying to solve by showing the same HH:MM value, could you update your question to address this?

Comment: I edited the question with more in-depth on the reason we need this, I'm worried that if it's a limitation of Google itself we'll have to go back to sending .ics attachments.

Comment: In regards to your edit, our program is always using local physical locations, never online. So even if there’s two different time zones it should always be 1pm for example, across the board. Meaning that if a student in Japan signs up for a class at a university, the expectation is that they attend in person where a tiresome change would break that.

Comment: @CadenSumner in this case, you should be able to set the timezone of the physical location. Alternatively, if you have an address or coordinate, you can find the timezone for that.

Comment: refactoring a large SaaS application isn’t really in the scope of the question, if it’s not something Google Calendar supports it would make sense to switch back to .ics attachments, so if the answer to “does google calendar support this” is no, then I think I know how to move forward.